# Roatate image about it's center

Tags: android

I am trying an application like rotating image with motion sensor....My problem is that the image does not rotate about centre properly....And my angle range is 0 to 90 and 0 to -90..
And below is my code.....

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Bitmap arrow = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.arrow);
    int arrowW = arrow.getWidth();
    int arrowH = arrow.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = 1;
    float scaleHeight = 1;
    int centrex = arrowW/2;
    int centrey = arrowH/2;
    int X=108;
    int Y=100;
    int angle=0;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    matrix.postRotate(angle, X+centrex , Y+centrey );
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(arrow, 0, 0, arrow.getWidth(), arrow.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.drawBitmap(resizedBitmap, X, Y, null);
    invalidate();
}
```

I am getting the angle values from onCreate method.....Using orientation sensor(roll values)..
But When I rotate the screen my  image is  rotating but not exactly around the image centre..

Answer (score 0):

Rotation should not be concerned by X and Y :

matrix.postRotate(angle, centrex , centrey );